# Why doesn't this structure represent a substituted pentane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

In the following ASCI structure (single bond under "$\ce{CH}$" containing $\ce{CH2,CH2, CH3}$)

$$
\begin{align*}
\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2-&CH-CH3}\\
&|\\
\ce{&CH2-CH2-CH3}
\end{align*}
$$

The correct way to name it is "4-methlyheptane".

But when I do it the way I have been taught I get the following "4-propylpentane".
Here are my systematic steps:

Firstly, I count the longest carbon chain. In this case its 5 carbons together so suffix -pentane. Then I look to see if there are any branched chains and number it from left to right. In this case the branched chain is on number 4. The branched chain contains $\ce{CH2-CH2-CH3}$, resp. $\ce{C3H7}$, aka propyl.

Ergo, 4-propylpentane, however, the correct answer as mentioned above is 4-methylheptane.

How is it 'heptane' ? The longest chain has FIVE carbons. I got the '4-' part correct, but how is $\ce{CH2-CH2-CH3}$ Methyl? Is this a mistake in my book?

Answer (score 12):

You need to find the [longest continuous carbon chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Union_of_Pure_and_Applied_Chemistry#Organic_nomenclature) of:

$$
\begin{align*}
\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2-&CH-CH3}\\
&|\\
\ce{&CH2-CH2-CH3}
\end{align*}
$$

Stretch that out to $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH(CH3)CH2CH2CH3}$ (with the $\ce{-CH3}$ coming off of the $\ce{CH}$) and you'll see that the book is correct.  The "side chain" of $\ce{-CH2CH2CH3}$ is actually part of the main carbon chain.  As far as the numbering, counting from either side give the 4- position due to the symmetry of the molecule.

[image: 4-methylheptane]

Comment: If anybody knows how to better jury-rig the diagrams, I'm open to an edit.

Comment: Just draw it on paper and take a picture. The built in package is too limited to draw a compound of even this low level of complexity.

Comment: @jonsca I found this http://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/sketcher to be of use when no local chemeditor is available.

Answer (score 2):

The structure is misleadingly drawn.  The longest carbon chain is *not* this:

$$
\begin{align*} 
\color{red}{\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2 -}}&\color{red}{\ce{CH-CH3}}\\
&|\\
\ce{&CH2-CH2-CH3}
\end{align*}
$$

but this:

$$
\begin{align*} 
\color{green}{\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2 -}}&\color{green}{\ce{CH}}\ce{-CH3}\\
&\color{green}{|}\\
&\color{green}{\ce{CH2-CH2-CH3}}
\end{align*}
$$

That's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... 7 carbons.  Thus, this is a substituted heptane.  The single remaining carbon forms a methyl group, which is attached to the fourth carbon (from either end) in the heptane chain.  Thus, 4-methylheptane.